# Is it possible to clear force state focus from the code?

Tags: javascript, web-inspector

I have a specific task to add focus on element using force state. Could you tell me please if it is possible to clear(remove) this state from the code (JS)? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: With JS or through the web inspector?

Comment: @StayNoy with JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you forced the state with [the chrome dev tools](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/dom/#state), it seems like you can't remove that state with JS. You can only do it by re-clicking in the dev tools. It's probably the point of a "forced" state.

If you focused another way, you can use `element.blur()`.
See [HTMLElement.focus()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus)
and [HTMLElement.blur()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/blur)